# How to add "0," after each loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How to add "0," after each loop in Ruby (At the data: part of the series)

```
So first loop would 
show only the value 
next loop 0,value
next loop 0,0,value 
next loop 0,0,0,value
etc..




series: [
    <% @prot = ProjectTask.where("project_id = ? AND taskType = ?" ,@project.id, "Pre-Sales")%>
            <% @prot.each do |prt| %>
            <% hoursSum = 0 %>
          {
              name: '<%= prt.task_name%>',
              data: [(here after each loop of @prot i want to add "0," here)<% @taskHours = Effort.where(:project_task_id => prt.id) %>
                        <% @taskHours.each do |th| %>
                            <% hoursSum = hoursSum + th.hours %>
                        <% end %>
                        <%= hoursSum%>
              ]
          },<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<% @prot.each_with_index do |index, prt| %>
    ...
    <%= "0," * index %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

This logic seems too complex to be in a view - I would migrate it to a helper function that builds up the data array and call that instead.

I think you'll find it a lot easier to do what you want then without having to deal with all the clutter of the erb tags etc. There's lots of ways you could do it - Yossi's suggestion of using `each_with_index` is a perfectly good one.

Two little things though - I would advise against shortened names for stuff like `@prot` - just call it `@project_task`. It's more readable and you can guarantee you call it the same thing throughout your code (instead of having some places where you call it `@prot`, others where it's `@ptask` etc) which will save you more time than you lose typing a longer name, I promise you.

Also - you use camelCase for some of your variables - I would advise sticking with the Ruby convention of snake_case.